# How to insert a page jump and open a tab within the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert a link that will read "Click Here To View Warranty Details" Which Will Scroll down the page and open the return policy tab. I have used iframe codes but ebay won't accept it and it doesn't work. What other code could I use?

The "Return Policy" tab that I want to open is a bit more than halfway down the page by the "Information & Policies Section" 
www.ebay.com/itm/Kenwood-KDC-152-Single-Din-In-Dash-MP3-CD-Receiver-Front-3-5mm-Aux-Input-/390455268429?pt=Car_Audio_In_Dash_Receivers&vxp=mtr&hash=item5ae8f2944d

Thank you all for your help!

Why wont ebay accept this code, it only works in IE and Mozilla not once uploaded to ebay

```
<a href="nogo" onclick="location.href='#policies'; return show('tab3');">Click Here To View Warranty Details</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this HTML. I think it should work.

```
<a href="#nogo" onclick="show('tab3')">Click Here To View Warranty Details</a>
```

Comment: I was just about to post that code, it opens the tab but doesn't do the jump

Comment: Ok. Maybe instead of '#nogo' -> '#infoTabs' I think this must work.

Comment: Actually it works in internet explorer but in Mozilla I can't click the link did I do something wrong?
    <a href='#infoTabs' onclick="show('tab3')">Click Here To View Warranty Details</a>